# Remove from SortedMap in scala

Tags: scala, collections

I have some sorted map like this

```
val m = SortedMap[Long, String]()
val buffer = 1000
```

and a method

```
def m(l: Long, s: String) = {
    m + { (l, s) }
    //Now in order to avoid OutOfMemory
    //I want to keep in the m keys in the interval
    //[max - buffer, max]
}
```

How to remove all values from the map except `[max - buffer, max]`.

The method `from` is not what I want because it creates a *projection* and the entries are eligable for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

**Last N Elements**

If you just want to keep the right most N elements then [`SortedMap#takeRight`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap@takeRight(n:Int):Repr) will work since your keys are Ordered:

```
val updatedM = m takeRight buffer
```

**Within A Range**

If you want to keep the keys within a certain range then the [`--`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap@--(xs:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[A]):Repr) seems to be what you want:

```
val goodKeys = (max - buffer) to max

val updatedM = m -- (m.keys -- goodKeys)    //*
```

*updated per accurate comment by TheArchetypalPaul.

Comment: You remove exactly the keys the OP wants to keep. `m -- (m.keys -- badkeys)` should do it, though?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Answer updated per your suggestion.  Thank you for the correction.